# User uploading files to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nginx, carrierwave

In my app an user has the ability to upload their logo to display on their profile page (using Carrierwave + s3).

On my local app the image path is this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/iemarkt/uploads/user/logo/squaredeye_336x336.jpg

But on my Heroku deployed app the image path is "/assets/", which is causing an error and not letting the user upload the image.

Whenever I try to upload a file with Carrierwave + s3 on my Heroku app I get this error "We're sorry, but something went wrong.", looking into my log I see this error:

```
    2012-08-20T21:18:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/" for 24.90.124.181 at 2012-08-20 21:18:56 +00002012-08-20T21:18:56+00:00 app[web.1]:2012-08-20T21:18:56+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets"):
```

My store_dir

```
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/"
```

I unccomented this line in my production.rb (I read that Heroku uses Nginx, I dont know if there's something else I need to do to get Nginx to work.)

```
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

I really don't know why the path doesn't lead to my s3 account.

Here's my [app](https://github.com/chrisbedoya/markt)

Comment: But is saving the images on S3? Try removing this line from your carrierwave.rb:
config.fog_host = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/iemarkt'

Comment: Its not I get an error on Heroku saying that somethig went wrong.

Comment: But what error it gave? For the log you can see the exact error

Comment: 2012-08-20T21:18:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/assets/" for 24.90.124.181 at 2012-08-20 21:18:56 +00002012-08-20T21:18:56+00:00 app[web.1]:2012-08-20T21:18:56+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets"):

Comment: When I look at the broken image link the src is "/assets/" I know thats the error but I dont know how to change it.

Comment: I understand when you call your image, link returns as 'assets', is this your code you use to call the log: <% = image_tag (@ deal.user.logo,: class => 'company_logo')% >?

Comment: Yeah. It works fine on my local app.

Comment: Ok but you uploaded image? Then do a test run try this <% = image_tag (@ deal.user.logo.avatar,: class => 'company_logo')%>

Comment: Nothing changes. Thanks for the help tho, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to deploy your app and it works fine, see my user has an image uploaded

http://young-reaches-9187.herokuapp.com/deals/1

The only thing I changed was in the carrier wave settings, the region name was wrong:
you were trying to use the region

`'eu-east-1'`
which doesn't exists, so I changed it to :
`'us-east-1'`

The full list of regions is available here : http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

By the way you SHOULD NOT write your AWS credentials in your app. For instance I just uploaded to your bucket, but I could have detroyed your files.
You should use environment variables.

You should also add you database.yml in your .gitignore.